# Light bulb burning problem on a two lights luminaire

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I'll ask owner for an electrician, but we have a weird issue with one of our luminaire in our apartment.

It's a two bulbs luminaire and since a year or so, we've change bulb in it like... 5 times maybe. It was LED bulbs because you know, 2018. So after asking some people, they told me that maybe our lights switch does not support LED bulb. So, we put normal bulbs in, guess what, two bulbs burn in two weeks. Bulbs literally burnt (it was all black in it every time) but it's always only one bulb and it seems to be always the same side.

So I bought few other bulbs, changed the luminaire for a new one too and installed it to finally put newly bought bulbs in... guess what happened again? I've change my third globes again in 2 months. And still same result; bulb get almost pitch black with a metallic reflect.

What can it be?
Is there something else I can test on my own?

Because our appartment owner is not really on our side when comes time to take money out.

### EDIT

Here is an image a power board similar to ours (not mine) but pretty similar (took in Google). Consider that ours is much more messier than that tho.

[image: Similar to our Power Board]

Comment: Thanks. If you have normal bulb burning out, then any kind, cfl, led, halogen, etc, will also burn out. If its the same socket every time, then that socket has an issue. Its shorting or is cracked or wires are coming off.

Comment: By socket, you mean the metallic box itself, in my ceiling and not the luminaire? Can it be dangerous?

Comment: The luminaire socket where the bulb screws into. Or could be on the box the luminaire attaches to. If it has more than 1 bulb and all bulbs burn out, then the box wiring or the luminaire could be the issue. If you have 2 or more bulbs, and only 1 burns out all the time, then that 1 socket is the issue.

Comment: An example of a lamp socket: 
       http://www.goodmart.com/products/miller-oem-corporation-mogul-base-porcelain-hid-pulse-rated-lamp-socket-l8746f.htm

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand. As told in my third paragraph, I've changed the luminaire for a new one. But bulbs still burn but still and only on one side.

Comment: There would then be a wiring issue in the box.

Comment: When using halogen bulbs, does the light sometime flicker? What kind of wiring have you got?

Comment: I haven't tried halogen yet but with regular one, before bulb burnt, there was a whole evening where the bulb closed for while and then open back again for 15 minutes, flickers during 10 minutes then closed and reopened 5 minutes after to finally burnt the day after. This is with the newly bought luminaire.

Comment: Are the wires solid core or flexible? How old is the installation? Can you post a pic of the wiring?

Comment: Ah man, it's an old house. Its turning hundred this year. Wires from the switch itself, i don't know. But in the box of the luminaire, it's old school black hard wire with a... kind of cord surrounding it. I'm not home right now to show you an image but as soon as I get it open I'll show you.

Comment: Crap, I know these wires. Old rubber insulation which used to be flexible but is now hard and turns into dust when you touch it? With cotton fabric  around it?... Be careful while manipulating them, these old wires are trouble. Try to post pictures. I'm really surprised these wires still exist. Probably illegal... Also post pic of power panel please.

Comment: This house needs a lot of love, let me tell you that. But there is always a dollar sign, you know. If I was owner, I'd change/fix it. But well no, in fact I would never own this house. And, you are right, wires are so hard that I had difficulty to bend it on the luminaire connector and put it back in. And they indeed turn into dust, like an old cardboard/cotton fabric. I even though that it could be asbestos so I quickly fix it and stop touching it.

Comment: We really, really super need to know your nationality (and which power system you're on if you're in the Philippines or Ecuador).  Certain power systems are vulnerable to certain failures that others are not.  If in EU/230V system, does your house have two *phases*?

Comment: I'm Canadian, Quebec province to be more specific. I have a regular power board using "switch", not "fuse" I think. I'll add an image to my main post.

Comment: Zut!  You are in North America and your house has two *poles*, which creates the same risk as two *phases*.   Any chance you own a voltmeter? Can you measure voltage on any of the 120V sockets and make sure it resembles 120V?  Ones in that same room would be preferable, or even better the lamp sockets proper, say via a [screw-in NEMA 1 socket](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Socket-with-Outlets-White-R52-01403-00W/100184555) and an extension cord added to that...  the thing to watch out for is voltages *over* 125V anywhere.  That is an emergency if so.

Comment: Well you know what. Starting there are things way over my knowledge. I'll rush my owner to call someone qualified and won't take any chance with that. You are a bit scaring the hell out of me right now.

Comment: @SimonDugré It's unlikely but if true, super urgent to fix.  I'm talking about a lost neutral in a split 120/240V system (either the whole house or just that circuit if it's a MWBC circuit) causing voltage to go under or over 120V depending on what else is on.  It's the worst case of a loose wire.  More likely is a regular case of a loose wire, which isn't great but *in my opinion won't burn out LED bulbs*.  Hence my concern.

Comment: I'll let you guys know once electrician get a look at it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Oops, since your name sounds French I thought you were, sorry about that. If you have 2-pole/biphasé and the neutral wire is disconnected voltage can increase at the sockets, and your appliances won't like this! But the most likely is a bad contact or bad switch which makes the light turn on and off many times (or flicker) which will kill the lightbulb quickly. This is less of a problem... still a fire hazard though as the bad contact can heat up and spark, which is no good if your house is built with wood! Better have an electrician look at it.

Comment: FYI, you were right. I'm not "french" but "French Canadian". In quebec, we mostly talk french ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I haven't tried halogen yet but with regular one, before bulb burnt, there was a whole evening where the bulb closed for while and then open back again for 15 minutes, flickers during 10 minutes then closed and reopened 5 minutes after to finally burnt the day after. This is with the newly bought luminaire. –

That's very important information.

If the light blinks and flickers with the new light fixture, then something must be wrong either with how you installed it, or most likely in the wiring or switch. Suspect a loose screw somewhere, or a defective switch.

Check the switch for loose/not tightened screws or bad connections (cut the power first, of course), and check the screws in your power panel (tableau électrique). Maybe the switch itself is bad and needs to be replaced.

Do not turn it on unless you're around, as loose connections can start fires.

Will update when you tell more.

Comment: I'm pretty much confident with my installation as the problem was there before I changed the luminaire. I'll take a look at the switch but for the power panel, well, a professional will take a look at it I think. This is getting over my limited electrical skill haha. If you tell me it's serious enough, I'll talk to our house owner